# Can lowered second degrees be used when switching music from major to minor even though they aren't actually part of the minor scale?

Tags: key

What I noticed in some songs is the second degrees of the scale rarely get turned into lowered second degrees when switching music from major to minor by lowering the third, sixth and seventh degrees. But normally, the second scale degrees aren't lowered when switching music from major to minor by lowering the third, sixth and seventh degrees because the lowered seconds aren't even part of the Aeolian mode which it equals to the natural minor scale.

Example: A song in B♭ major would use the notes "B♭CDE♭FGA" but when switched to B♭ minor by lowering the D, G and A notes, the notes would become "B♭CD♭E♭FG♭A♭". Normally the C notes would remain the same when switching a song from B♭ major to B♭ minor since the C flats are not even part of the B♭ Aeolian mode which equals to the B♭ natural minor scale. But in rare cases, the C would become C♭ in certain parts of some songs.

Example: The piano song called Frankie and Johnnie from the Alfred's Adult Piano Course Level 2 book is in the key of B♭ major but has some E♭ major notes in it which that has a similar melody to the main melody of the actual key of the song which is B♭ major. If the song was played in B♭ minor, the C notes which are second scale degrees in the B♭ minor scale could be flattened for the E♭ major parts of the Frankie and Johnnie piano song just like how the G notes are flattened in the main melody of Frankie in Johnnie but in B♭ minor.

I understand that lowering all or most of the second degrees of the song in minor key would make it Phrygian, but lowering just a few second degrees of the song in minor key wouldn't necessarily make it a song in Phrygian mode. So it makes me wonder if the lowered second degrees can be used when switching music from major key to minor key despite the lowered second degrees are not actually part of the minor keys.

Comment: I think what you’re asking about is a lowered second scale degree when changing modes, does that seem right? I’m afraid I’m a bit confused by the question. To me a minor second is an interval of a half step and both major scales and minor scales have two minor seconds per octave.

Comment: @ToddWilcox and the harmonic minor scale has three.

Comment: False premises - Aeolian is only one of three sets of notes which constitute 'minor' - and that's before minor modes are considered. And isn't ^2>^3 M2 in major, always going to m2 in minor? Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I was talking about if the lowered second degree can be used when transposing music from major to minor even though it’s not actually part of the minor scale since I noticed in some songs is the major seconds rarely get turned into minor seconds when transposing music from major to minor.

Comment: I don't understand *when* or *why* you'd be "transposing" from major to minor.

Comment: Usually “major second” and “minor second” refer to intervals, not scale degrees. I think you might want to edit your question to replace “minor second” with “lowered second degree”. Otherwise this question is really hard to understand.

Comment: Also it would help to add some kind of example. It’s not clear what you mean by “transposing major to minor”. Do you mean a change of mode to the parallel minor? Or a modulation from a major key to a close or distant minor key? Maybe if you actually pick two keys to discuss, like writing “let’s say I wanted to modulate from C major to Eb minor, would I put in a Db somewhere before the modulation?”

Comment: "...But in rare cases..." Post the example you're talking about. It's too hard to know what you're thinking, but I suspect it might be part of a modulation in the piece, some kind of move toward the subdominant, which one thing that lowering the second degree in minor means.

Comment: Are you trying to analyze a particular use of a lowered second scale degree?  It would commonly occur when modulating to some tonality other than the parallel minor, for example to A-flat major or F minor in C major, but it could also occur in a particularly chromatic passage in the parallel minor.  It could even occur in a chromatic passage in the major key, although in that case you would more likely see a raised tonic than a lowered supertonic (that is, C sharp rather than D flat in C major).

Comment: You can probably get this reopened if you post the actual rare case you were dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the lowered/flattened second scale degree can be used when "transposing"/shifting music from a major key to a minor key, but it may sound weird.**

"Transposing"/shifting music from a major key to its relative minor is common in classical music, especially minor-key sonata-allegros. While flattening the supertonic a.k.a. the second scale degree in the minor-key version is rare in such sonata-allegros, it has been done, although it often involves a "transposition" that is significantly less than perfect (e.g. something other than the second scale degree is replaced with the lowered second scale degree).

Take these two examples from classical music:

**Piano Sonata No. 8 in C Minor, Op. 13 "Pathetique" by Ludwig van Beethoven, 1st movement** ([recording](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Beethoven%2C_Sonata_No._8_in_C_Minor_Pathetique%2C_Op._13_-_I._Grave_-_Allegro_di_molto_e_con_brio.ogg))

Recapitulation, shifted to C minor from E flat major (starts in 5:35 of recording):

[image: Pathetique Sonata, Beethoven, recapitulation, 2nd theme group, 2nd theme]

Original (in exposition), in E flat major (starts in 2:40 of recording, top staff uses treble clef):

[image: Pathetique Sonata, Beethoven, exposition, 2nd theme group, 2nd theme]

**Keyboard Sonata in E minor, Hob.XVI:34 by Joseph Haydn, 1st movement** ([recording](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/5/5a/IMSLP364617-PMLP01714-Haydn_Sonata_in_E_minor-I.Presto.mp3))

Recapitulation, shifted to E minor from G major (starts in 3:21 of recording):

[image: Keyboard Sonata in E minor, Hob.XVI:34, Haydn, recapitulation, 2nd theme group]

Original (in exposition), in G major (starts in 0:46 of recording, top staff uses treble clef):

[image: Keyboard Sonata in E minor, Hob.XVI:34, Haydn, exposition, 2nd theme group]

In both of these cases, the flattened supertonic is harmonized with a chord that emphasizes how foreign that note is to the base minor key, such as vii°4/3 of iv (for the Beethoven) and ♭II6 a.k.a. the Neapolitan (for the Haydn).

Flattening the supertonic when "transposing"/shifting music from a major to a minor key just might be more common in video game music, although it can have a strange and pointed effect again, and it still can often involve "transpositions" that are significantly less than perfect. Take these 2 examples from the Kirby series:

**Kirby: Triple Deluxe**

- Minor-key version with lowered 2nd scale degree: ["The World to Win"](https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/kirby-triple-deluxe-sound-selection/mqhegwxeud/40%20The%20World%20to%20Win.mp3), final boss theme involving automatic power-up (first use of lowered 2nd scale degree is at 0:14)
- Major-key original: ["Hypernova
  Inhale"](https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/kirby-triple-deluxe-sound-selection/gduxqeemxt/04%20Hypernova%20Inhale.mp3), theme of said power-up (equivalent is at 0:05)

**Kirby and the Forgotten Land**

- Minor-key version with lowered 2nd scale degree: ["Morpho Knight"](https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land-switch-gamerip-2022/ddwtugzsfp/085.%20Morpho%20Knight.mp3), cutscene and boss theme (first relevant use of lowered 2nd scale degree is at 1:14, "transposition" notably sometimes retains raised 3rd scale degree)
- Minor-key version *without* lowered 2nd scale degree for comparison: ["The Beast Pack's Final Stand"](https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land-switch-gamerip-2022/iqmzipadks/060.%20The%20Beast%20Pack%27s%20Final%20Stand.mp3), late-game stage theme (equivalent starts at 1:45, more minor-key "transposition"s start earlier)
- Major-key original: ["Ready to Go"](https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land-switch-gamerip-2022/tdnccexheu/001.%20Ready%20to%20Go%21.mp3), title theme (equivalent starts at 0:44, this "original" actually picked for convenience due to sharing a tonic with both minor-key versions above)

Note that all the minor-key examples with the lowered 2nd scale degree are for boss themes (where the higher tension the lowered 2nd scale degree provides may be more appropriate), with "Morpho Knight" in particular using the lowered 2nd scale degree earlier in the theme and its "tranposition" using the lowered 2nd scale degree likely to remain consistent with that earlier trend.

Comment: In the Beethoven example is makes much more sense to call that Db `FA` - scale degree ^4 - relative to the Ab chord, not a lowered RE, ^2, because it is functioning as FA resolving to MI.

Comment: The Haydn example does have the lowered ^2 sound, it's a N6 chord.

Answer (score 1):

'Transpose' is the wrong term for a mode change.  But we can let that pass.

If you're submitting an exercise in theory class, and the brief is 'transform this major key piece to minor', you would be well advised to leave diatonic 2nd degrees of the scale unchanged.

If you're composing music, with no imposed restrictions, you can do what you like. An occasional flattened 2nd degree may well be effective.  But when you use one you won't be transforming major to minor any more, you'll be transforming major to Phrygian, if only momentarily.